# Jquery Mobile - Dynamic Pages Accumulating in the DOM

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on a simple Jquery Mobile application that does a search, presents results, and then allows you to click on a result to go to a dynamic detail page.  On the detail page there is a collapsible list which uses an ajax call to get its content.

It appears to be working fine on the surface, but when I inspect it with Firebug I notice that every time you go to a detail page and expand the collapsible list, the ajax fires multiple times.

So, for instance, I do a search, go to the detail page, expand the collapsible list, the ajax fires once.  I go back to the results page, click on another result, go to the detail page, expand the collapsible list, and the ajax fires twice, etc. Each time I expand the collapsible list, the ajax fires one more time...so if I look at 10 results, the ajax fires 10 times.

It would appear that the dynamic pages are accumulating in the DOM, and each time I click on the collapsible list, it's firing on all the selectors that have built up in the DOM (at least that's my theory).

How do I make sure that my ajax only fires once rather than multiple times?

I'm using Jquery Mobile 1.0.1 with Jquery 1.6.4. I'm using php to get the data.

Here's my code for the search page:

```
$('form#searchCompanies').submit(function(event) {
    getSearchResultsCompanies();
    return false;
});

function getSearchResultsCompanies() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseURL + 'server/searchCompanies.php',
        data: $("form#searchCompanies").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(results){ 
            $('#companyList li').remove();
            for ( var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $('#companyList').append('<li><a href="' + baseURL + 'companyDetail.htm?companyid=' + results[i].CompanyId + '" data-uid="' + results[i].CompanyId + '" class="companyDetail">' + results[i].CompanyName + '</a></li>');
            }
            $('#companyList').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$('.companyDetail').live('click', function(event) {
    //save companyid so that we can reference it on detail page
    var companyid = $(this).attr('data-uid');
    localStorage.setItem('thisCompanyId', companyid);
});
```

Here's the code for the detail page:

```
$('#companyDetailPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    var companyid = localStorage.getItem('thisCompanyId');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseURL + 'server/getCompanyDetail.php?companyid=' + companyid,
            data: {companyid: companyid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(company) {
                $.each(company, function(index, company) {
                    $('#companyName').html(company.CompanyName);
                    //etc...pulls in more data to populate the page
                });
            }
        });


    //this is the call that fires multiple times
    $('#companyContacts').live('expand', function(event) {
        $('#companyContactList li').remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseURL + 'server/getCompanyContacts.php?companyid=' + companyid,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results){ 
                for ( var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    $('#companyContactList').append('<li>' + results[i].LastName + 'etc...more data</li>'); 
                }
                $('#companyContactList').listview('refresh');           
            }
       });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The html div that gets populated looks like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" id="companyContacts" class="cmdCompanyContacts">
    <h3>Contacts (<span id="totalContacts"></span>)</h3>
    <ul id="companyContactList" data-role="listview"><li></li></ul>
</div>
```

I've searched high and low for a resolution, and tried reworking my code from various angles, but I'm not able to solve this problem.  Any help would be deeply appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. I tried the suggestion found [here](http://richardsweeney.com/blog/jquery-mobile-events-firing-multiple-times-and-what-to-do-about-it/), but still had the multiple event triggering problem after trying this. Here is what else I had to do. I changed it from this:

```
$(‘#myPage’).bind(‘pageinit’, function (event) {
$(‘#myButton’).live(‘click’, function (event, ui) {
```

to this:

```
$(‘#myPage’).bind(‘pageinit’, function (event) {
$(‘#myButton’).click(function (event, ui) {
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked! The only drawback for me is that I wanted to use 'expand' as my event in this particular situation, and $('#myButton').expand... threw an error. So in order to use click, I would need to detect whether the collapsible element was expanded or contracted.  So, in the end, I did a little more reading and discovered that you can in fact use jquery 1.7.1 with jquery mobile, so I used 'on' instead of 'live' ... and all my problems were solved!  Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using jquery live i would like to suggest you to use javascript function call when you click for the page change.Write your ajax call in that function so that its been called only once.Hope this helps

Comment: I assume you mean like this: $('#button').click(function(e){...  Yes, this indeed worked; except $('#button').expand(function(e){... didn't work.  I ended up using jquery 1.7.1 and 'on' instead of 'live' and everything now works beautifully.  Thank you.